# Unveil Hidden Partitions Created by Malware in Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Background:

My computers are infected with Malware that is preventing me from fully cleaning the storage drives.  I know this because even when I boot from and OEM installation disk, when I use the disport command "clean" or "clean all" and then begin to create partitions for a windows installation, I get an error message stating that no more primary partitions may be created after I create one, but no other partitions or volumes are visible.  I realize that the ID of the partition may prevent visibility if it is one that is not recognized by Windows, but if I boot to a live Linux USB, there is also no visibility of additional partitions unless I use fdisk to view the partition details of a specific partition such as /dev/sda1 (I have already asked a separate questions pertaining to this issue).

Question:

Is there a way view hidden and/or partitions unrecognized by Windows, in Windows 10?

Comment: Just overwrite the first MB of the disk with zero, the end? There is no way to hide partitions from `fdisk`.

Comment: @Daniel B  I have tired this multiple times but the end result is always the same, which is where the malware still persists.  I'm not sure if it is loaded into memory and then writes itself back to disk after or if I'm getting a false report of trying to write to disk.  I've used other programs where I get error messages when trying to write to sector 0 of the disk or VBR when booted to an alternate shell.

Answer (score 0):

There are many disk management tools, such as the free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), which can view and mount partitions in a variety of formats, such as *ext4*, which MS applications do *not* recognize.

That said, some malware is *extremely* difficult to remove. If you've tried booting from rescue media (not from the infected drive!) with antimalware utilities, such as [BitDefender](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-create-a-bitdefender-rescue-cd-627.html), [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/thank-you/free-rescue-disk), or [Trend Micro](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/forHome/products/free-tools/rescue-disk.html), and the partition is still there, your best choice is to rescue what data you can and then repartition and format the drive.